# How to mock Class object or how to mock private generic method

Tags: mockito, powermockito

I have a private generic method below

```
private Section convertFromJsonToJavaObj(JSONObject jsonObj, Class<Section> classObj) throws SNPSysException {
    // logic
    return section;    
}
```

how to mock above method

Answer (score 0):

Testing private methods is generally a code smell. We generally only test public methods.

However if there is a quite complex logic in it and you really need to test it, you can remove the `private` modifier.

```
Section convertFromJsonToJavaObj(JSONObject jsonObj, Class<Section> classObj) throws SNPSysException {
     // logic
     return section;    
}
```

This way your test will be able to access this method if it's in the same package (except that it should be in the `test` folder instead of `main` folder)